# Using OMP_SCHEDULE with #pragma omp for parallel schedule(runtime)

Tags: c++, openmp, schedule

I am trying to understand how to use the `schedule(runtime)` directive of OpenMP in C++. After some research I found [`OMP_SCHEDULE(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxdty0df%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`OMP_SCHEDULE(2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0e208df9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I concluded that I need to set the varibale `OMP_SCHEDULE` to a certain value. 
However, I don't know how to do that and I have not found any working C++ examples that explain me how to correctly do so.

Can some one explain me how to set variable and provide a working C++ example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 4 types of OMP scheduling. They are static, dynamic, runtime and guided. Each scheduling has its advantages. The scheduling is present for better load balancing among the threads.

I will give you some example for static and dynamic scheduling. It is similar for the guided as well.

The schedule(runtime) clause tells it to set the schedule using the environment variable. The environment variable can be set to any other scheduling type. It  can be set by

```
setenv OMP_SCHEDULE “dynamic,5”
```

**Static Scheduling**

Static scheduling is used when you know that each thread will more-or-less do same amount of work at the compile time.

For example, the following code can be parallelized using OMP. Let assume that we use only 4 threads.

If we are using the default static scheduling and place pragma on the outer for loop, then each thread will do 25% of the outer loop (*i*) work and eqaul amount of inner loop (*j*) work Hence, the total amount of work done by each thread is same. Hence, we could simply stick with the default static scheduling to give optimal load balancing.

```
float A[100][100];

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
   {
      A[i][j] = 1.0f;
   }
}
```

**Dynamic Scheduling**

Dynamic scheduling is used when you know that each thread won't do same amount of work  by using static scheduling.

Whereas, in this following code,

```
float A[100][100];

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
      A[i][j] = 1.0f;
   }
}
```

The inner loop variable *j* is dependent on the *i*. If you use the default static scheduling, the outer loop (*i*) work might be divided equally between the 4 threads, but the inner loop (*j*) work will be large for some threads. This means that each thread won't do equal amount of work with static scheduling. Static scheduling won't result in optimal load balancing between threads. Hence we switch to dynamic scheduling (scheduling is done at the run time). This way you can make sure that the code achieves optimal load balance.

Note: you can also specify the chunk_size for scheduling. It depends on the loop size.

Comment: Actually `schedule(runtime)` instructs OpenMP to use the scheduling type given by the _run-sched-var_ internal control variable. Setting `OMP_SCHEDULE` is only one of the two possible ways to set _run-sched-var_. Implementations are allowed to provide special scheduling types beyond `static`, `dynamic`, and `guided` and these can only be enabled using `omp_set_schedule()`.

Comment: Also note that `static` is NOT the default scheduling. The default is controlled by the _def-sched-var_ ICV and its value is _implementation-specific_. It might happen to be `static` as with many current OpenMP runtimes but there is no guarantee that it will stay the same in the future.

Comment: @veda: I know what dynamy is, I know what static is and I know what guided is. I have no problem in using them separately. However, I don't know how to change them dynamically by setting the OMP var. Can you provide me a C++ code that does that?

Comment: What do you actually mean by change them dynamically? You mean you want your code to automatically select the scheduling on run time?

Comment: You can specify the scheduling by having "#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)" above the for loop